# SharePoint 2013, change welcome page layout when a sub site is created

Tags: sharepoint

we have a custom page layout, and we want this:

When a new sub site is created by users, we want the default.aspx, AKA welcome page to be based on our custom page layout.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1) Create a custom web template and define a module for the welcome page. This obviously only works for that custom web template, but does not require code.
2) Create a web event receiver (e.g. WebProvisioned), apply it to site collection. In the code behind set the page layout of the welcome page to your custom page layout. This works for any template, but requires custom code.

Option 1 only works in a farm solution, option 2 should also work in a sandboxed solution I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want this OOTB (Codeless).

1. Go to page (you want to make home page) set the layout. (you custom
   layout).
2. Set this page as a home page.
3. Remove all data (lists, libraries, pages). except this page.
4. Save the site as site template(_layouts/savetmpl.aspx). If you are not finding the save as template option. Write the url.
5. After saving the template, you can
6. use the same template for all your sites. For creating subsites,
   this should be add in list site template in settings. Let me know, I
   can explain you more.

Thanks